# Windows became a black and white frame with full inner transparency when dragging it

Tags: windows-7

I am using a 64 bit windows 7 with Intel 2600 processor and a gigabyte durable series motherboard. My monitor resolution is 1920 x 1080. Recently I notice my window,s become a black and white frame with full inner transparency when dragging it.  This how it is looks like:

[image: inner transparency]

I also notice that my loading arrow is changed to this:

[image: loading arrow].

What can I do to bring back my arrow and remove the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the Start Menu, right click **Computer** and click on **Properties**. Alternatively, navigate to **Control Panel** -> **System and Security** -> **System**.

[image]

2. Click **Advanced System Settings** on the left.

[image]

3. In the **Advanced Tab**, click the **Settings** button under **Performance**

[image]

4. Ensure **Show window contents while dragging** is checked.

I'm not sure about the mouse cursor change, it could be related to the **Show shadows under the mouse cursor** item.

Alternatively, click **Adjust for best appearance** or **Let Windows choose what's best for my computer**